# Bash: escaping variables

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash one liner.
This works (prints date to the console or tries to execute it):

```
-bash-4.1$ DATE=`$(date --date="2 days ago" +%F)` echo "${DATE}"
```

But this:

```
`DATE=$(date --date="2 days ago" +%F)` psql -d some_db -c "select row from table where started >= '${DATE}' and started < ('${DATE}'::date + '1 day'::interval);"
```

Gives:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
LINE 1: ... table where started >= '' ...
```

Which means that `${DATE}` is empty there.
What should I modify to make it work?

Comment: Why are you mixing `$(...)` and then old back-ticks in same command?

Comment: Yeah, but at least it knows about name, it's clearly not an empty string in the first example.

Comment: Your first line will produce `bash: 2016-08-23: command not found` error. It should be: `DATE=$(date --date="2 days ago" '+%F') && echo "$DATE"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command is broken for a couple of reasons. Firstly, you are mixing backticks and `$()` in such a way that you are executing the output of the `date` command as if it were the name of another command.

To save the output of a command to a variable, use this syntax:

```
output=$(command)
```

Secondly, the variable would be expanded by the shell before it had been assigned a value, so you need to split up the command into two statements:

```
date=$(date_command); psql -c "select ...  '$date'"
```

...or use a command substitution directly:

```
psql -c "select ...  '$(date_command)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do the date math in bash? PG can do it directly:

```
SELECT ... WHERE started >= (datefield - interval '2 day')
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The question was how to do it in bash. Please abstract away the fact that this is PG, it may be other command where you need to use date.